# Autogenerated DataGrid TwoWay binding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` defined as follows:

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="ColumnGrid"
              ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Columns, Mode=TwoWay}"
              CanUserAddRows="True"
              CanUserDeleteRows="True">
</DataGrid>
```

VM:

```
private ObservableCollection<ColumnRow> _columns;

public ObservableCollection<ColumnRow> Columns {
    get {
        if (_columns == null) {
            _columns = new ObservableCollection<ColumnRow>();
        }

        return _columns;
    }
    set {
        throw new Exception("asdf"); //for debugging purposes
        _columns = value;

        RaisePropertyChanged("Columns");
    }
}
```

Problem is that when I edit something on my `DataGrid`, no row is added to the Columns collection (and no `Exception` is thrown).

Comment: Exception definitely gets thrown but that is not fatal because any exception raised at target update from binding is considered as validation error. What exactly you want to achieve by throwing exception?

Comment: It's for debug purposes only, earlier I had something like `MessageBox.Show("asdf");` but it wasn't shown either so I figured that something is wrong and this code is not being run.

Comment: No the code definitely runs. You can verify that by placing breakpoint there. It's just that any exceptions thrown will be treated as error and in case you want to listen to it, you have to set `ValidateOnExceptions=True` on your two way binding to show error validation template on control.